# Saving parent of hasMany record causes children to disappear from view

Tags: ember.js

Whenever I save a parent record the children visible in the view flash then disappear. I can still see them in the data view inside Ember inspector but not in the view tree. This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475199/ember-data-child-records-disappear-from-screen-after-one-flash-when-created) but the single answer does not fix the issue. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ld7gf/13/) is an updated fiddle from that question.

Models

```
Todos.Todo = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  quarters: DS.hasMany('quarter',{async:true})
});

Todos.Quarter = DS.Model.extend({
  filled: DS.attr('boolean'),
  todo: DS.belongsTo('todo')
});
```

Action

```
//Save the child and then the parent

quarter.save().then(function () {
  //Succesful save of child; thus add to parent

  todo.get('quarters').then(function(quarters){
    quarters.pushObject(quarter);
    todo.save();
  });
});
```

This happens when todo.save() is called and happens regardless of context to the child record.

Comment: ``//Save the child and then the parent

quarter.save().then(function () {
  //Succesful save of child; thus add to parent

  todo.get('quarters').then(function(quarters){
    quarters.pushObject(quarter);
    todo.save();
  });
});``    -- if you replace the todo.save() with quarter.save() -- 4 checkboxes with true show up. You look like youre close just need some fine tuning...

Comment: moving the todo.save() outside of the first .then function also shows up the checkboxes but they all seem bound to each other

Comment: Ah you're correct! I'm curious as why calling todo.save() elsewhere causes the issue. Something to do with promises? Thanks for helping and ember noob, wish I could mark your comment as the correct answer

Comment: but its not really - shouldnt the checkboxes be independent of each other?
Why todo.save() might be causing issues elsewhere is because its in a loop so every time a quarter gets pushed it todo gets saved - so each new save is overriding the last

Comment: Yeah I gotta little excited when they didn't disappear, this does *not* fix the issue in the example even though the child elements do not disappear. Calling todo.save() anywhere (i.e. by itself, not in a loop) causes the issue

Comment: I suspect `todo.save()` removes relationship since ED expects a response from adapter and saves that response in store. Even though you're passing ids of quarters on quarters association probably LS replies without them. I also suspect that only one quarter is passed to quarters association on that hours loop but five times however I don't know how only one of quarters is added considering in each iteration you're creating a new quarter.